# Module import issue for Python/Kivy-iOS/Xcode environment

Tags: python, ios, xcode, kivy

Beginner of Python/Kivy-iOS programming. Trying to make cross-platform application on Mac.
Following shows super-simplified code.

```
<Main.py>
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
import datetime
import pytz

class MyApp( App ):
    est = pytz.timezone('US/Eastern')
    est_now = datetime.datetime.now(tz=est)
    def build( self ):
        return Button( text=self.est_now.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S') )

MyApp().run()
```

This runs with no problem on Terminal. (Python 3.7.3 by Anaconda)
However after running following script, Xcode terminal shows following error, which says no 'pytz' module.

```
<timetest.sh>
./toolchain.py create testpytz /users/(username)/Programming/Python/Sandbox/TestPytz
cd testpytz-ios
open testpytz.xcodeproj

<Error message>
Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "/Users/(username)/Pip/kivy-ios/testpytz-ios/YourApp/main.py", line 4, in <module>
 ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pytz'
```

What I found is that the Xcode terminal also says,

```
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.7.1 (default, Aug 15 2019, 15:08:22)
```

Seems like this is not the same Python version as my terminal one. Is Xcode using different python? How I can install pytz module to the python used by Xcode?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like you are using different Python versions in Anaconda and Xcode. You can install a conda environment with the dependencies you need creating a yml file like this

```
name: newenvironment
dependencies:
- python==3.7
- anaconda
- pandas
```

and you can create that environment with `conda-env install -f file.yml`

To access that environment, just type `source activate newenvironment`

Comment: Thanks a lot. I think what you mentioned is to make a virtual environment for my app. (conda env create -f=file.yml, correct?)

Comment: Then how can I let X-XCode use this enviroment?

Comment: Found in one webpage that toolchain.py does not work for pytz.